# Dynamic Programming On Intervals

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

You are a given an array of contiguous intervals i.e. `{ [a,b],[b,c],[c,d],...,[g,h],[h,i] }`

Given a query of type `n m k`, we need to output the number of intervals between `n,m (inclusive, 1-based indexing)` containing `k`.

My Approach : ( Naively check for all the intervals between `n,m` and keeping a counter. )

This works if `m-n` and number of queries are small, but this would be really inefficient for larger values of `n,m` and multiple queries.

So I was thinking of a Dynamic Programming approach such that we can save number of intervals containing `z` upto an interval numbered say `x` in the array `dp[x][z]`, then I can answer any query `n m k` as `dp[m][k]-dp[n][k]`. But this also fails if intervals given in the array are too large as it would take greater time to construct the `dp` array.

How do I get around this or is there a simpler approach that I am missing?

Any hints would be helpful.

Example :

Array : `{ [1,3],[3,2],[2,1],[1,5],[5,3] }`

Queries : `{ 1 2 2 }` , `{ 1 3 3 }` , `{ 2 2 4 }`

Output : `{ 2 }` , `{ 2 }` , `{ 0 }`

Comment: Please add some example of input and expected output of your question.

Comment: Can you explain more what's wrong with the naive approach. For me it is O(N) and does not depend on the length of intervals. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Sarmon: the question is how to optimize this for **multiple queries**.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem the following way.

First I would introduce another array of data structure of the form:

```
[(ai,bi,ci)]
```

where

```
ai - interval start
bi - interval end
ci - count of intervals of original sequence hitting interval [ai,bi]

ai < bi
a(i+1) = bi
```

so this new data structure covers whole range of original structure, it is increasing and it has the desired count of original interval.

Now to find the count we only need k and perform some kind of binary search to find the interval.

Comment: Can you please explain it using the given example?